# Getting class not found exception in java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to create a database connection between java and mysql. This is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Java2MySql {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

    String dbName = "sh";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "shakti";

    try {
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  shakti");

      while (res.next()) {
        int id = res.getInt("id");
        String msg = res.getString("name");
        System.out.println(id + "\t" + msg);
      }

      conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at Java2MySql.main(Java2MySql.java:13)
```

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: Well have you got the relevant driver jar file on the classpath?

Comment: Thanks for ur support..Sir i want to know onething after downloading that jar where i have to keep that jar file and another thing is i have installed mysql 5.1.72 in my laptop but i have downloaded the jar file 3.1.14 . Whether it will work properly or show some problem. Thnaks Binay.

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't add the .jar driver to your class. 
If that's not it I would suggest going here [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2012/03/jdbc-javalangclassnotfoundexception.html) to check other reasons.

Comment: Thanks for ur support..Sir i want to know onething after downloading that jar where i have to keep that jar file and another thing is i have installed mysql 5.1.72 in my laptop but i have downloaded the jar file 3.1.14 . Whether it will work properly or show some problem. Thnaks Binay.

Comment: In order for everything to work well you have to add the .jar to the classpath. You could add it in the folder of the project in some /lib folder and after that add it in the classpath.Regarding the jdbc driver, you should check the vendor's website that provides it.

Comment: Thank you so much i got the output...